# Kubernetes - Ingress v1

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have some troubles to setup an ingress resource on top of a GKE cluster.
I'm having a **404 error response** on any type of HTTP requests.
The following are my deployment, service and ingress configurations:

Deployment and service:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: snap-api
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: snap-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: snap-api
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: snap-ksa
      containers:
      - image: eu.gcr.io/snap-xxx/services/snap-api:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: snap-api
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001
          protocol: TCP
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "200Mi"
            cpu: "200m"
          limits:
            memory: "1Gi"
            cpu: "1"            
        env:
          - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
            value: Production
          - name: CONFIG_CONNECTION_STRING
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: snap-secrets
                key: config_connection_string
          - name: DATA_CONNECTION_STRING
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: snap-secrets
                key: data_connection_string
          # TODO: Dev cert               
          - name: TLS_KEY_PATH
            value: /app/aspnetapp.pfx
          - name: TLS_KEY_PASSPHRASE
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: snap-secrets
                key: tls_key_passphrase   
      - name: cloud-sql-proxy
        image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
        command:
          - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
          - "-instances=snap-xxx:europe-west1:snap-tenant-db=tcp:1433"
        securityContext:
          runAsNonRoot: true
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1433
          protocol: TCP          
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "500Mi"
            cpu: "1"
          limits:
            memory: "2Gi"
            cpu: "1"                 
      restartPolicy: Always
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: snap-api-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: snap-api
  ports:
    - targetPort: 5001
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 60000
```

And the ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: snap-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - pathType: Prefix
          path: /api/*
          backend:
            service:
              name: snap-api-service
              port: 
                number: 60000
```

I was wondering that can by a firewall problem? Also healt checks are failing on my service...
The following is the output of "kubectl describe ingress snap-ingress" command:

```
Name:             snap-ingress
Namespace:        default
Address:          x.x.x.x
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (10.6.0.2:8080)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /api/*   snap-api-service:60000 (10.6.0.130:5001)
Annotations:  ingress.kubernetes.io/backends:
                {"k8s-be-31084--19bd63f37342a0f0":"HEALTHY","k8s1-19bd63f3-default-snap-api-service-60000-d79961e6":"UNHEALTHY"}
              ingress.kubernetes.io/forwarding-rule: k8s2-fr-2zv080r1-default-snap-ingress-4rmjay2y
              ingress.kubernetes.io/target-proxy: k8s2-tp-2zv080r1-default-snap-ingress-4rmjay2y
              ingress.kubernetes.io/url-map: k8s2-um-2zv080r1-default-snap-ingress-4rmjay2y
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  Type    Reason     Age                   From                     Message
  ----    ------     ----                  ----                     -------
  Normal  Sync       7m18s                 loadbalancer-controller  UrlMap "k8s2-um-2zv080r1-default-snap-ingress-4rmjay2y" created
  Normal  Sync       7m16s                 loadbalancer-controller  TargetProxy "k8s2-tp-2zv080r1-default-snap-ingress-4rmjay2y" created
  Normal  Sync       7m6s                  loadbalancer-controller  ForwardingRule "k8s2-fr-2zv080r1-default-snap-ingress-4rmjay2y" created
  Normal  IPChanged  7m6s                  loadbalancer-controller  IP is now x.x.x.x
  Normal  Sync       112s (x6 over 8m50s)  loadbalancer-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Comment: which url did you test to get a 404?

Comment: The ingress public ip:
```
Normal  IPChanged  7m6s                  loadbalancer-controller  IP is now x.x.x.x
```

Comment: did you try x.x.x.x/api/?

Comment: x.x.x.x is just a placeholder to avoid to write the real public ip of my cluster.
I try to login in my snap-api application with a POST request: http://<public-ip>/api/users/login

Comment: Do you have logs on your container in Cloud Logging? Do you see a requested URL? I suspect a wrong rewrite on your ingress.

Comment: I don't see any errors in container, service or ingress logs

Comment: Do you have an Ingress Controller installed? Without an Ingress Controller, Ingress resources don't do anything. Public cloud providers usually give you an Ingress Controller by default. When installing kubernetes on your own, by my knowledge, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

After a few days it seems to have been decisive to implement the health check on the Web Api application at the url: "/".
After this change, it began to work.